# Having trouble using thesurus api on android

Tags: android, api, thesaurus

I am trying to have a  text-box that will connect to this 
http://thesaurus.altervista.org/service
service and when a button is clicked it will  give me a list of synonyms for the word entered in the text-box.

I am still starting with android so if you can help Thank You in advance.

Comment: What problem you are faced when you implement your functionality?Share some code

Comment: I have no idea how to implement the api. i don't know how to right the code for the button to send the http request and get the data.

Comment: You should read this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/ and prepare some code and still you face some problem then ask here, Because no one know what is your requirement. Mean how you want to implement and what is your `UI`.

Comment: Thank you for the info. This link is a good help.

Comment: Ok if i have any problem i will ask here. Thank you again

Comment: If you face any problem after implementing some code then i will be here.Good luck